# Backbone.js Add URL Parameter for PUT and POST when Saving Models

Tags: post, backbone.js, put

I'm working with Backbone.js, and have a collection of models. The RESTful service I'm integrating with requires me to add a "r=true" parameter to the URL to get a JSON representation of the model in the response (which is needed to get the id back during a POST). Is there a way to add that parameter to the URL when POST or PUT is done when I call model.save()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/ with something like:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options ) {
    // check if the method is PUT or POST
    // check if there is no parameter, add ?r=true, otherwise add &r=true
    options.url = options.url + "&r=true"; 
  }
});
```